# RaisePropertyChanged doesn't work for collections

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding, mvvm-light

I'm using mvvm-light and I noticed this strange behavior about the RaisePropertyChanged.

xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
```

Observable class:

```
public class A : ObservableObject
{
    private string _b;
    public string B
    {
        get { return this._b; }
        set
        {
            this._b = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("B");
        }
    }
}
```

vm:

```
public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService) { this.Collection = new List<A>(...); }

public RelayCommand Command1
{
    get
    {
        return this._command1 ?? (this._command1= new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            this.Collection.Add(new A());
            this.Collection[2].B = "updated";
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Collection");
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
        }));
    }
}

public RelayCommand Command2
{
    get { return this._command2?? (this._command2 = new RelayCommand(() => { this.Text++; })); }
}

public List<A> Collection { get; set; }
public int Text { get; set; }
```

So, RaisePropertyChanged("Collection") doesn't update the binding while RaisePropertyChanged("Text") do. I can see it by executing the Command2 several times and the Command1 after that. If the Collection is an ObservableCollection then new element shows in a view, but updated item isn't, which means an internal mechanism of an ObservableCollection works, but not the RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: Have you implemented `INPC` for your class A?

Comment: @RV1987, ObservableObject implements.

Comment: As long as property you are setting is raising `PropertyChanged` event, UI gets update.

Comment: @RV1987, the fact is it doesn't. Moreover, GetBindingExpression(...).UpdateSource() for Collection's ItemsSource also doesn't update UI, but `var dc = this.DataContext; this.DataContext = null; this.DataContext = dc;` updates it correctly.

Comment: I tried your sample with `INPC` implemented by class `A`and it works for me though.

Comment: @RV1987, You have tried it for a WindowsPhone7?

Comment: Oops.. I tried for simple WPF application.

Comment: I see the problem but I don't quite understand what the question is. You already have a workaround, do you want an explanation of the problem? Another workaround?

Comment: @KooKiz, I don't have a workaround, the mentioned one with nullification doesn't fit me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, an explanation of the issue:

On Windows Phone, when setting a value for a dependency property, the framework internally check if the new value is different from the old one (for optimization purpose maybe). When you raise the `PropertyChanged` event or directly re-assign your collection to the `ItemsSource` property (which is just a wrapper around the `ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty` dependency property), the framework detects that the value actually didn't change and doesn't update the property. Therefore, the `ListBox` is never notified of your changes, and isn't updated.

The `ObservableCollection` works because it uses a whole different mechanism: the `ListBox` directly subscribes to the `CollectionChanged` event of your collection, and thus isn't hindered by the limitations of the dependency properties.

---

Now, how to get around this limitation? The only workarounds I can think of are:

1. Use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`
2. Assign `null` to the `ItemsSource` property of your `ListBox`, then re-assign your collection
3. Bind the `ListBox` to a property that will return a different collection every time it's called:

   ```
   public List<A> CollectionCopy
   {
       get
       {
           return this.Collection.ToList();
       }
   }
   ```